# Spring integration tcp-connection-factory closes client connection before reply

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I have some problem with spring-integration.
Lets say, that there is my outgoing communication configuration:

```
<int:channel id="outputChannel">
    <int:queue /> 
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="outputChannel-in"> <!-- for response from server -->
    <int:queue /> 
</int:channel>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory 
    id="outputSocket"
    type="client" 
    single-use="true"
    host="localhost"
    port="666" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="outputChannel"
    reply-channel="outputChannel-in"
    connection-factory="outputSocket"
    reply-timeout="20000" />

<int:gateway id="myGateway"
     service-interface="some.package.SocketGateway"
     default-request-channel="outputChannel"
     default-reply-channel="outputChannel-in" />

<int:service-activator
    id="myServiceActivator" 
    input-channel="outputChannel-in" 
    ref="myService"
    method="incomingDataHandlingMethod" />
```

No matter what I'll do with interface some.package.SocketGateway:

option #1:

```
public interface SocketGateway{
    byte[] send(String text);
}
```

option #2:

```
public interface SocketGateway{
    Future<byte[]> send(String text);
}
```

It doesn't receive any message.
I played with configuration a lot. It is only one version of my solutions, but none of them worked.

Here is a server mock:

```
ServerSocket someSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
Socket socket = someSocket.accept();

PrintWriter  out =
    new PrintWriter (socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

System.out.println("socket accepted");

String data = in.readLine();
while (data != null) {
    System.out.println(data);
    data = in.readLine();
} 

System.out.println("data received");
out.println("ACK");

out.flush();  
System.out.println("data sent");
socket.close();
someSocket.close();
```

When  `out.println("ACK");` is after while, connection closes and ACK is not sent. When `out.println("ACK");` is before while or inside, it sends message.

What should I do to receive this message?

EDIT:
I tried also with:

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outboundClient"
    channel="outputChannel"
    connection-factory="outputSocket" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="outboundClient-in"
    channel="outputChannel-in"
    connection-factory="outputSocket" />
```

Without good results.

*EDIT:*
I've this client side code:

```
Socket echoSocket = new Socket("10.20.30.40", 11111);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

String encodedMessage = "someMessage";

String result = String.format("%c%s%c%c", (char) 11, encodedMessage, (char) 28, (char) 13);

            out.println(result);
out.flush();
System.out.println("data sent");

File file = new File("result.txt");
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

String data;
while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
    output.write(data);
}

output.flush();
output.close();

System.out.println("after while");
out.close();
in.close();
echoSocket.close();
```

And this works fine with external server (server is synchronously sending ACK message, which is received in *String data*. How to achieve this result with Spring Integration? I can't receive anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a stream; it needs structure to delimit messages. The default deserializer expects CRLF at the end.

Send `out.println("ACK\r\n");`.

You can read about `Serializer`s and `Deserializer`s [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

**EDIT:**

Your logic is flawed in several ways.

1. Using `PrintWriter.println()` only appends LF; you need CRLF unless you change the deserializer.
2. Your "server" is hung on `readLine()` until the socket is closed.

This works fine:

```
ServerSocket someSocket = new ServerSocket(1666);
Socket socket = someSocket.accept();

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +  " socket accepted");

String data = in.readLine();
System.out.println(data);

System.out.println("data received");
out.write("ACK\r\n".getBytes());

out.flush();
System.out.println("data sent");
socket.close();
someSocket.close();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If I'll send some message in while or before, it will be received by client socket. When I invoke send on interface it sends message, waits 20seconds for reply and then raises `org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response`. If send is in while, it goes to reply-channel and then service-activator method is invoked.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for Your reply. Now it works. This was only some Mock, on the other side is another server, but right now I know that my configuration is fine, they will have to solve this problem, not me :)

Comment: Hello, I still have a problem with receiving data from external server. Simple java client works fine, but spring integration does not receive data

Comment: More information in second Edit in main question - thanks in advance!

Comment: As I said before, if the server is only delimiting the data with a `LF`, instead of `CRLF` (which is what the default deserializer expects), you need to change the serializer/deserializer to a `ByteArrayLfSerializer`. Please read the documentation I referred you to.

Comment: Thank You very much! Everything works with custom Serializer / Deserializer. Regards :)